# Merging Row_Number column with other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, row-number

I have a table called `People` that has two columns, `Name` & `Age`. I'd like to write a query that will retrieve the Name column with the `row_number` merged into each row. something like this : -

```
       Name
-------------------
[ROW_NUMBER] Stan
[ROW_NUMBER] Alex
[ROW_NUMBER] Steven
```

Row number being 1,2,3, Whilst adding the brackets as well.

This is what I tried

```
Select ( '[' + row_number() OVER (order by Name) + ']' + Name) From People
```

Comment: You haven't stated which SQL engine - SQL Server, MySQL, etc? (tagging it will help visibility which may help give better answers)

Comment: You're right, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select  '[' + cast(row_number() OVER (order by Name) as varchar(100))  + ']' + Name From People
```